# How to pass a release variable in a powershell script in XlRelease

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, smb, xlrelease

I'm trying to automate the generation of a certificate for our IIS. To accomplish this, I am using a PowerShell command to convert my Base64 private key to PFX format and download it. Since this process is automated, I need to pass the private key as a release variable in XL Release. However, I am encountering difficulties in achieving this.

I tried this but it didn't work :

`>powershell -command "$certificateBase64 = $using:releaseVariables['Certificate64Base']; $decodedPrivateKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($certificateBase64); $privateKeyFilePath = 'C:\test_private_key.pfx'; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($privateKeyFilePath, $decodedPrivateKey)"`

quick update i tried this:

```
powershell -command "$certificateBase64 = '${Certificate64Base}'; $decodedPrivateKey = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($certificateBase64); $privateKeyFilePath = 'C:\test_private_key.pfx'; [System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($privateKeyFilePath, $decodedPrivateKey)"
```

but i got :

The task could not start because the following variables could not be replaced: ${Certificate64Base}. Ensure that global and folder variables are defined, there is no circular references, password variables are only used in password fields, and other variables are only used in non-password fields.

Comment: What happens? Errors? If so, what do the error messages say?

Comment: I'm getting :
A Using variable cannot be retrieved. A Using variable can be used only with Invoke-Command, Start-Job, or InlineScript in the script workflow. When it is used with Invoke-Command, the Using variable is valid only if the script block is invoked on a remote computer. At line:1 char:1 + $certificateBase64 = $using:releaseVariables['Certificate64Base']; $d ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UsingWithoutInvokeCommand

Comment: Did the XlRelease documentation suggest you should be able to retrieve release variables with `$using:...`?

Comment: They say nothing in there doc i tried the using but it didn't work

Comment: The certificate has an encryption mode.  The IIS has to support the encryption mode.  Window Server 2012 is old and does not supported the latest encryption modes.  You may need to use a different certificate with an encryption mode that the 2012 can use.  Look at note 1 at bottom of following webpage.  RSA256 is not supported on IIS.

Comment: @jdweng Just a heads up - you didn't post the webpage link.

Comment: Here is the lonk : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/architecture/client-access/certificates?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: Hi, I don't have a problem in the certificate it works perfectly my issue is in the xlr variable it doesn't work when i pass it in xlr powershell command what i did is i request the download of the certificate via the api and it returns me a private key in base64 and i need to convert it to pfx and save it in my remote machine .

Comment: quick update i tried to do like this : 
powershell -command "$certificateBase64 = '${Certificate64Base}'; 
but  i'm getting :
The task could not start because the following variables could not be replaced: ${Certificate64Base}. Ensure that global and folder variables are defined, there is no circular references, password variables are only used in password fields, and other variables are only used in non-password fields.